# What is data.tar.gz

Tags: 18.04, tar, ubuntu-mate

I found data.tar.gz in /home/andy/home/files/ and it's almost 1 Gb in size.

A search found little info about. What is it for ?

Comment: It could be *anything*, really - based on the name, it *might* be the result of unpacking a `.deb` file: see for example [Packaging System: Tools and Fundamental Principles - Structure of a Binary Package](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/packaging-system.html#sect.binary-package-structure)

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to be sure what it contains unless you open/extract it to check it out, you can do that through the file manager since it'll open in archive manager by default, or if you want to look at it from the terminal use the tar command:

```
tar -tvzf ~/data.tar.gz
```

Since you have no memory of putting it there, it was probably downloaded by some script that didn't do it's part cleaning up after it's run, but based on the name, a few guesses of what it could be would be:

- an extracted `.deb` package as a regular package [uses that archive to store all the package files](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/packaging-system.html#sect.binary-package-structure)
- A flashable android [kernel file](https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_htcuniversal/downloads/data.tar.gz/)

Comment: The tar contains my whole home directory(including all subdirectories and files). I wonder if I can delete it?

Comment: @fixit7 Considering that you know no application that uses it, it would be safe to delete

Comment: I moved it to a different drive just in case. If nothing happens, I will delete it.

Comment: @fixit7 If it contains your whole home directory, there's a chance it could be from a backup utility. Have you used any backup software lately?

Comment: Backup last ran on Aug 16 2018. Date is different than that of data.tar.gz. I am loosing some rep on this question.